# how to change drop down border color in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, colors

I want to put validation in drop down as the way of border color red after not selecting option.

```
$("#MainContent_ddlSuppliers option:selected'").css("border", "1px solid #F78181");
```

Comment: You can't style specific option in select.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a JS plugin to style option elements. JCF is just one example of such a plugin - https://www.psd2html.com/js-custom-forms/#demo